# Linux/bash/awk read parts of the files name as variables

Tags: python, linux, bash, csv, awk

We wrote an awk one liner to split an input csv file (Assay_51003_target_pairs.csv) into multiple files. For any row if their column 1 is equal to another column column 1, the column 2 is equal to another column 2, etc., these rows will be categorized into a new file.  The new file will be named using the column values.

Here is the one liner

```
awk -F "," 'NF>1 && NR>1 && $1==$1 && $2==$2 && $9==$9 && $10==$10{print $0 >> ("Assay_"$1"_target_"$3"_assay_" $9 "_bcassay_" $10 "_bcalt_assay.csv");close("Assay_"$1"_target_"$3"_assay_" $9 "_bcassay_" $10 "_bcalt_assay.csv")}' Assay_51003_target_pairs.csv
```

This will generate the following example output (Assay_$1_target_$3_assay_$9_bcassay_$10_bcalt_assay.csv):

Assay_51003_target_1645_assay_7777_bcassay_8888_bcalt_assay.csv

```
51003,666666,1645,11145,EC50,,0.2,uM,7777,8888,IC50,,1,uM,,3,2.0555,3011-02-0100:00:00,1911-04-1100:00:00,Cell,Biochemical
51003,666666,1645,1680,EC50,<,0.1,uM,7777,8888,IC50,,1,uM,,2,2.8579,3004-06-0300:00:00,3000-04-1100:00:00,Cell,Biochemical
```

Assay_51003_target_1645_assay_7777_bcassay_9999_bcalt_assay.csv

```
51003,666666,1645,11145,EC50,,0.2,uM,7777,9999,IC50,,1,uM,,3,2.0555,3011-02-0100:00:00,1911-04-1100:00:00,Cell,Biochemical
51003,666666,1645,1680,EC50,<,0.1,uM,7777,9999,IC50,,1,uM,,2,2.8579,3004-06-0300:00:00,3000-04-1100:00:00,Cell,Biochemical
```

Assay_51003_target_1688_assay_7777_bcassay_9999_bcalt_assay.csv

```
51003,666666,1688,11145,EC50,,0.2,uM,7777,9999,IC50,,1,uM,,3,2.0555,3011-02-0100:00:00,1911-04-1100:00:00,Cell,Biochemical
51003,666666,1688,1680,EC50,<,0.1,uM,7777,9999,IC50,,1,uM,,2,2.8579,3004-06-0300:00:00,3000-04-1100:00:00,Cell,Biochemical
```

Later on we would like to do, for example,

```
awk -F, -f max_min.awk Assay_51003_target_1645_assay_7777_bcassay_8888_bcalt_assay.csv

awk -F, -f max_min.awk Assay_51003_target_1645_assay_7777_bcassay_9999_bcalt_assay.csv

awk -F, -f max_min.awk Assay_51003_target_1688_assay_7777_bcassay_9999_bcalt_assay.csv

#################################################

for b in 1645 1688

do

     for c in 8888 9999

     do

     awk -F, -f max_min.awk Assay_51003_target_$b_assay_7777_bcassay_$c_bcalt_assay.csv

     done

done
```

However, we don't know if there is any way to write a loop for the followup work because the outfile names are "random".  May we know if there is any way for linux/bash to parse part of the file name into loop variables (such as parse 1645 and 1688 into b and 8888 & 9999 into c)?

Answer (score 1):

With Bash it should be pretty much easy granting the values are always numbers:

```
shopt -s nullglob

FILES=(Assay_*_target_*_assay_*_bcassay_*_bcalt_assay.csv)  ## No need to do +([[:digit:]]). The difference is unlikely.
for FILE in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    IFS=_ read -a A <<< "$FILE"
    # Do something with ${A[1]} ${A[3]} ${A[5]} and ${A[7]}
    ...

    # Or

    IFS=_ read __ A __ B __ C __ D __ <<< "$FILE"
    # Do something with $A $B $C and $D
    ...
done
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your kind comment! "#IFS=_ read -a A <<< "$FILE"" line seems to bring errors.  If I mute it and activate the "IFS=_ read __ A __ B __ C __ D __ <<< "$FILE"" line, the output seems correct.   Could you kindly add more comments for the script?  Couldn't fully understand some points such as "shopt -s nullglob", "FILES=(Assay_*_target_*_assay_*_bcassay_*_bcalt_assay.csv)",""${FILES[@]}", "IFS=_ read __ A __ B __ C __ D __ <<< "$FILE".  Thanks!

Comment: @Chubaka Can you tell me the version of Bash you're using? (`bash --version`). Also make sure you run your script explicitly with bash e.g. `bash script.sh`.

Comment: `nullglob` enables bash shell option `nullglob` that prevents presenting the glob pattern if no file is found out of it.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

Comment: @Chubaka It's really likely that you're calling the script with `sh` e.g. `sh script.sh`) or that your header is `#!/bin/sh`. It should be `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: I kind of ignored your request sorry. `IFS=_ read __ A __ B __ C __ D __ <<< "$FILE"` calls `read` with `IFS` set to `_` during its run. With IFS set to `_`, read parses the input with tokens separated by `_`. Since you provided more variables, each token gets assigned to each of them. And the tokens that gets assigned to A, B, C and D are the only ones that we need.

Answer (score 0):

Asking if `$1 == $1`, etc., is pointless, since it will always be true. The following code is equivalent:

```
awk -F, '
  NF > 1 && NR > 1 {
    f = "Assay_" $1 "_target_" $3 "_assay_" $9 \
        "_bcassay_" $10 "_bcalt_assay.csv"
    print >> f;
    close(f)
}' Assay_51003_target_pairs.csv
```

The reason this works is that the same file is appended to if the fields used in the construction of the filename match. But I wonder if it's an error on your part to be using `$3` instead of `$2` since you mention `$2` in your description.

At any rate, what you are doing seems very odd. If you can give a straightforward description of what you are actually trying to accomplish, there may be a completely different way to do it.